# Loading a view with laravel Excel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-excel

I'm trying to export a view in laravel, using

https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel

The problems is that I'm getting this error with my css file `"file_get_contents(/css/all.css): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"` It could not find my file when I press the button to export, but if I don't my page loads normally, once i had this same problem and i just had to go one folder back to access to my files, but it didnt work this time

this is my code in my controller

```
    public function exportar($empresa_id, $id)
    {
        $empresa = Empresa::where('id', $empresa_id)->first();
        $transferencia = $empresa->transferencias()->where('transferencia_id', $id)->first();
        $destino = Empresa::where('nombre', $transferencia->destino)->first();
        Excel::create('New file', function ($excel) use ($empresa, $transferencia, $destino) {

            $excel->sheet('New sheet', function ($sheet) use ($empresa, $transferencia, $destino) {

                $sheet->loadView('acciones/imprimirTransferencia', array('empresa' => $empresa, 'transferencia' => $transferencia, 'destino' => $destino));

            });

        })->export('xls');

    }
```

My css link

```
  <link href="{{ mix('/css/all.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

My button

```
  <a href="{{url('exportar/transferencia/'.$empresa->id.'/'.$transferencia->id)}}" id="exportar_excel" class="btn btn-success pull-right"> Generar PDF                
 </a>
```

Comment: try to give the css the full URL or, if that fail, an absolute filesystem path. But only in the excel rendering view.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I dont know why but I solved writing all the path. If you want to try.

This **WORK** for me

```
<link href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

**NOT work** with my public direction

```
<link href="{{ mix('/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Your css name are diferent of course.